# echo multiple divs with content from DB and fill width of container div side by side

Tags: php, mysql, css, ajax

I know there are similar topics to this but I think mine is a bit different.  What I'm doing is echoing content in a div with data from database.  They are a part of an ordered list element.  First 10 items are loaded, user clicks Load More and 10 more loads.  Right now they are in one column as an ordered list...I want the echoed divs to be two side by side in a line.  I think I need to keep it as an ordered list because the ordered list gets appended with html content through an ajax call.  I tried using jQuery masonry and successfully made the divs side by side for the first 10 but the next 10 didn't because the DOM wasn't refreshed...and that's how masonry works.  So I'm wondering if I can do this with CSS.  Anyway...here's my code:

```
<body> 
<div id='container'>
   <ol class="row" id="updates">
<?php
  //query DB for content
?>
   <li> <?php echo "<div style='font-size:12px; position:relative; left:300px;>
        //some other divs with content from DB
        </div><br>"; ?> </li>
        <?php } ?>
   </ol>
<div id="more" style="margin-top: 20px;"> <a  id="<?php echo $id; ?>" 
     class="load_more" href="javascript:void(0);">Show More</a> </div><br/>
</div>
</body>
```

That's my initial body code.  In the add_more_content.php called by ajax, the format is the same and it returns the same div style and appends to the ordered list id "updates".  And this is some css I have for this:

```
ol.row {
  list-style:none
}
ol.row li {
  position:relative;
  padding:8px;
}
#container {
  width:600px
}
.load_more {
  position:relative;
  left:220px;
  display:block;
}
```

So is it possible to make the echoed divs side by side until they fill up the container div width?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: By using `float:left;`, or `display:inline-block;`?

Comment: I think because it's an ordered list, it is going to display it in a list...i tried float:left before and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `display: inline` on the li?

Comment: I just deleted the ordered list completely and now I'm appending straight to the container div and it's still working properly.  I think that will help instead of making the lists...now I need to make them fill the container div...maybe I can just display:inline the echoed div?

Comment: See this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uwaqej/1/edit

Comment: @estrar That almost worked but now my load_more button jumps to the middle of the screen if I use float:left...it doesn't stay at the bottom of the page. display:inline doesn't work either...

Comment: I can't reproduce it. http://jsbin.com/uwaqej/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

They should line up by themselves if you use display inline (I tried both on the li and on the inner div elements), but I see you have some typos in your posted code so I don't know if it may be causing your issues.

For example you are not closing the ' in the inline style for your inner divs... I also suggest using a class for styling, in that way you'll be really sure your elements share their css, and you'll be able to edit them at runtime using Firebug (or other browser's equivalent)...

EDIT for "Show More" button purpose:
If the appending html is breaking your button behavior, you can move it out of the container so it keeps in position, and you can even add a parent container to contain both the self-updating div and the updater button... this way you should be able to keep your contents correctly styled and positioned.

Comment: The inline is closed...sorry that was a type when I was placing the code here.  It's closed in my code.

Comment: Ok, did it work displaying inline both the li and the inner div?

Comment: nope :( just messed everything up on the page. I give up...I'll just keep it how it is...I've messed around with this for a really long time and it's not working.

Comment: I'm sorry... don't give up, maybe you just have to change your strategy, for example avoiding ordered lists and using divs directly... every dom node can accept append via ajax calls, not only ols... :)

Comment: I did do that...I deleted the ols and lis...just used append to the container div and i still couldn't get it.  It's just when I used float:left, most of them lined up correctly but the Show More button jumped to the middle of the page and didn't stay at the bottom. I'm adding the css code for the load_more button...maybe it's something there?

Comment: Then try moving the "Show More" button outside the container, so it keeps its position while the container grows, maybe a solution... you can also add a new container to contain the current container and the button, even if this sounds like a tongue twister... :)

Comment: :) a bit of a tongue twister.  I'll just keep it as is...I'll fill the page with other content so it doesn't look so empty around the content.  Thanks for helping!